# How to add attributs to my gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm currently making a simple ruby gem which fetch data from an existant api and show it on demand.

```
require 'net/http'

module SimpleGem

@@api= 'http://api.example.com'

def self.exec
  reponse = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(@@api))
  result = JSON.parse(reponse)
end


end
```

The basic way to access to data is

> demo = SimpleGem.exec()
>   demo[:title]

I would like to handle it as objects so i can access data like this :

```
demo = SimpleGem.exec()
demo.title 
demo.description
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to design an object with it's supporting attributes/properties.  So, in your case, title and description are properties of your object SimpleGem.  The next step is to either use a constructor or accessors (getters/setters) to populate your objects.

```
class SimpleGemObject

 #constructor
 def initialize(title,description)
  @title = title
  @description = description
 end

 #accessor methods
 def title=title
  @title = title
 end

 def description=description
  @description = description
 end
end
```

This gives you a good starting point and you can read more about object oriented principles in ruby [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_object_oriented.htm)

**UPDATE**
Whether you adopt the construct approach or accessor approach, it's really upto you.  Here's an example of the constructor approach:

```
def self.exec
 reponse = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(@@api))
 result = JSON.parse(reponse)
 sampleObject = SampleObject.new(result[:title], result[:description])
end
```

Your self.exec will now return an object of type SampleObject.  Now, when you call demo = Sample.exec, you'll be able to access title and description attributes as you wanted:

```
demo.title
demo.description
```

Comment: If i make a class object for my gem and i set attributes after fetching data, how could the module return an attribute from gem's class object

Comment: thanks for your help @rb512 and sorry for my noob questions. I am discovering yet Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it now but maybe this can help you

```
# your module
require 'ostruct'
...

def exec
  reponse = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(@@api))
  OpenStruct.new(JSON.parse(reponse))
end
```

Comment: it doesn't work, i tried :  test = OpenStruct.new(response)
test.results.movie.title (json skeleton : results -> movie -> title)

Comment: as I know OpenStruct perform what you want but only one level. it mean that in your case `test.result #=> {movie => title}`. So I think you should follow @rb512's answer and build real object yourself